# gzip - break common compression levels

Tags: compression, gzip

I know that gzip supports 9 compression levels, from fast to strong.
The decompression algorithm does not care about the compression level at all.
Is it possible to reach a "higher" level than 9 by another tool than the common gzip application?
I mean, someone could have created a modified gzip compressor which is more effective than gzip level 9.

The background is that I have a webserver which hosts compressed gz files. It would be nice to reduce the sizes of those files and I do not care how long my server has to work in order to reduce those files even by 1 byte at the end. It is a one-time task, so it does not matter.

Is there something like a hacked version of gzip supporting higher levels or offering higher compression?

Comment: If it's *hacked* then it stops being GZip and is custom and then both ends need to support it. If you control both ends you're free to use whatever algorithm you see fit.

Comment: No, you can "hack" the compressor without "hacking" the format, so that it is still decompressible with gzip on the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's called [zopfli](https://github.com/google/zopfli). It is painfully slow, but will compress about 5% better than zlib level 9. zopfli is built in to [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/), which is a gzip equivalent that makes use of multiple processors and cores. Compression level 11 in pigz invokes the zopfli compressor. (pigz goes up to 11. Get it?) Using multiple cores on large inputs helps mitigate the slowness of zopfli.

Comment: Are 1-9 levels in gzip like levels in bzip2? Bzip2 uses level to change block size like 100000 byte block for -1 and 900000 bytes for -9: http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/html/memory-management.html.

Comment: It is "like" them in that it trades time for compression. It is unlike them in that in zlib it does not change a block size, but rather the degree to which the compressor searches for matching strings.

Comment: There was blog post about Zopfli (https://developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/compress-data-more-densely-with-zopfli.html) and paper (Data_compression_using_Zopfli.pdf) about it (but can't find online copy of it now, it is not in https://github.com/google/zopfli after migration from code.google)... Update: copy of the paper http://web.archive.org/web/20130402101541/http://zopfli.googlecode.com/files/Data_compression_using_Zopfli.pdf. Is there explanation  (other than source code) about how zopfli works and why is can compress better?